# Rxjs bind context of place where observable was created

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an array of observables which was created in a loop. And then merged all these observables using `merge`, and subscribed to the merged observable. I could not find a way to retrieve context of observable where it was created (in loop). Here is code

```
let observable = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(request);
let streams = _(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
 .someMoreLodashStuff()
 .map(val => {
   // HERE SOMEHOW I WANT TO BIND CONTEXT (e.g. loop val),
   // SO THAT SUBSCRIBER CAN KNOW THE EXACT LOOP STATE
   // WHEN RECEIVING RESULT
   return observable(mutate(val))
 })
 .value();

Rx.Observable
.merge(...streams)
.subscribe(
  (res) => {
   // HERE I WANT TO GET CONTEXT (e.g. val)
  }, (err) => {
   // HERE I WANT TO GET CONTEXT (e.g. val)
  },
  () => {
    //on complete stuff
  });
```

**Update (as asked by @martin)**

Since @martin asked about purpose of this binding and what problem I am trying to solve, so I will describe the real problem.

**Pupose and real problem**

I am trying to crawl list of websites (passed as query params), fetch their titles and render them in an html and return the html back to user. This is part of my [open source repo](https://github.com/hhsadiq/async-lab), where solved this exact problem using node.js callbacks, async.js waterfall and promises. Now solving it using rxjs. Its just a way to learn different async techniques. This is [file from github repo](https://github.com/hhsadiq/async-lab/blob/master/server/titles/streams/titles.service.js) where using rxjs to solve this problem

Comment: You could return `this`from the first map(). I don't understand what's this supposed to do or what problem you're trying to solve. Why should subscribed know the context used somewhere from map() operator?

Comment: @martin updated the question. I guess now you can better understand real problem, And you can see that returning `this` from first `map` will cause `Rx.Observable.merge()` to fail, because it expects Observables.

Comment: I also tagged you in github (@martinsik) at exact line in file where I want binding. I hope that might give you better answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to retain a reference to the input state you could use the [`flatMap`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) overload which takes a `resultSelector` function to create a tuple containing the merged input + output state:

```
// given a function which can return the body of the page requested
function doRequest(url) : Observable<string>

const urls = Rx.Observable.from([a,b,c])
  .flatMap(
    a => doRequest(url),
    (a,res) => ({ url: a, body: res})
  )
  .subscribe(resTuple => console.log(`url ${resTuple.url} returned ${resTuple.body}`)
```

Comment: wonderful answer, exactly what I was looking. Thanks alot @Mark.

Comment: just one question, the resultSelector is only available on success handler, any way we can get on error handler

Comment: You can use a `catch` for errors from doRequest, would that Help?

Comment: yeah that's what I ended up using. this is [final file](https://github.com/hhsadiq/async-lab/blob/master/server/titles/streams/titles.service.js) after applying your suggestion.